# Why can't I throw an exception while using the ternary operator

Tags: java, android

This doesn't compile and gives the following error: `Illegal start of expression`. Why?

```java
public static AppConfig getInstance() {
    return mConfig != null ? mConfig : (throw new RuntimeException("error"));
}
```

Comment: because `throw` is not an expression

Comment: "return (throw new RuntimeException("error"));" - you can't return a throw new exception()

Comment: The Null Object pattern is worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because a ternary operator in java takes the form `expression ? expression : expression`, and you are giving a statement as the final part. This doesn't make sense as a statement doesn't give a value, while expressions do. What is Java meant to do when it finds the condition to be false and tries to give the second value? There is no value.

The ternary operator is designed to allow you to quickly make a choice between two variables without using a full `if` statement - that isn't what you are trying to do, so don't use it, the best solution is simply:

```
public static AppConfig getInstance() {
    if (mConfig != null) {
        return mConfig;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("error");
    }
}
```

The ternary operator isn't designed to produce side effects - while it can be made to produce them, people reading it won't expect that, so it's far better to use a real `if` statement to make it clear.

Answer (score 17):

You may write an utility method

```
public class Util
{
  /** Always throws {@link RuntimeException} with the given message */
  public static <T> T throwException(String msg)
  {
      throw new RuntimeException(msg);
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public static AppConfig getInstance() 
{
    return mConfig != null ? mConfig : Util.<AppConfig> throwException("error");
}
```

Comment: Why not declare `throwException` as returning `Object`?

Comment: @Navin Object requires cast at the caller. `T` doesn't need cast (at least some times... depending on the compiler). In Java 8 even `<AppConfig>` is not required (compiler can figure it out)

Comment: Ah ok, that's convenient :)

Comment: What is the Util class?

Comment: @jonsinfinity Util is the class where throwException is defined. I have updated my answer for clarity

Comment: You can create the method without the utility class where you need it. Use like: return mConfig != null ? mConfig : throwException("error")

Answer (score 6):

In case it's helpful to someone, here is an answer using java 8+ Optional:

```
public static AppConfig getInstance() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(mConfig).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("error"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return a `throw new RuntimeException("error")`. That is why you are getting error. Because in `true` case you are returning `AppConfig` and in `false` case you are returning `exception`.

Answer (score 0):

By introducing a lambda function, the ternary operator can be used to throw an exception as follows:

```java
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public static AppConfig getInstance() {
    return mConfig != null ? mConfig : ((Supplier<AppConfig>) () -> {
        throw new RuntimeException("error");
    }).get();
}
```