# Ternary operator is not a statement

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ternary-operator

I've the following ternary expression:

```
((!f.exists()) ? (f.createNewFile() ? printFile() : throw new Exception("Error in creating file")) : printFile());
```

For one, or more, reason that I don't know idea IDE say to me that it isn't a statement. Why?

Comment: Without trying to answer the question, just one observation: Are you sure you want your code to look like this? I would kick myself if I wrote it like this and had to revisit it after a couple of weeks....

Comment: Yes for me is more readable and also I use comments in my code

Comment: What are you trying to achive with the throw? You know that the ternary operator only works with assignments?

Comment: Can you use `throw` in ternary expression?

Comment: @KevinEsche the ternary operator does not "only works with assignments".

Comment: Why use `f.exists()` and then `f.createNewFile()` ? - the latter will return false if the file already exists, there's no need to do a separate check first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not valid, you need to return a value

```
printFile() : throw new Exception("Error in creating file")
```

try this one

```
if(f.exists() || f.createNewFile()) {
  printFile();
}else{
  throw new Exception("Error in creating file");
}
```

Comment: I think the error is thrown with `f.createNewFile()` without throwing the custom exception. At least when i enter an invalid path for a file.

Comment: i think the proposed code shoud work in a different way, i have not changed functionality.

Comment: Answer accepted even if it's not exactly compliant with the question

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using it as a statement and not as an assignment

[From what SO says it is not possible to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977031/java-ternary-without-assignment)

[Also from another SO Articel, that says you can´t throw an exception in the ternary statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891841/why-cant-i-throw-an-exception-while-using-the-ternary-operator)

I think you need to go back to an if-else clause like this:

```
if (!f.exists()) {
   try {
      f.createNewFile();
      printFile();
   } catch(Exception e ) {
      System.out.println("Error in creating file");
   }
} else {
   printFile();
}
```

Comment: The links correctly explain the problem. Just your mention of *assignment* is a bit out of place: the elements of a ternary must be **expressions** (throw is not an expression) and the ternary itself must be used as an **expression** (it's used as a statement in the example). BTW, both Eclipse and javac report a **syntax error** on `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

The "COND ? Statement : Statement" construct is an expression. It can not be used as a statement.
Without assignment it can be used in situation like resolving condition argument in function call or string concatenation.

```
Func( (COND ? param1 : param2) );
"Hi"+(con?"Miss":"Mr.")+"";
```

Answer (score 0):

The statements in the **ternary operator** need to be **non-void**. They need to return something.

Example:

- Consider a case, where count variable gets incremented and I am checking for its value and return true or false above certain threshold.
- `System.out.println((count >10 ? true: false));`
- As compared to, `count >10 ? true: false` where compiler will complain that this is not a statement.